# How to apply divider or view in Constraint layout

Tags: android, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I want to apply a divider at some places in Constraint layout but when I do it by simple view, the whole layout get shifted to the top and everything gets merged. I want to use only constraints layout for the whole design.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="98dp"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Nivedita Parmar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
```

Please give some idea regarding this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: set constraint to divider also

Comment: where you want to put your divider?

Comment: Actually i'm trying to added full layout under constraints layout. If i put view put also same then i got everything compress or not in sequence as per i have made.

Comment: ya getting but where you want to put your view(divider)?

Comment: in between text view and image view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: layout]

See my answer below. I am putting view between text view. May help you.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context="com.example.shweta.firebasedemo.Main2Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/txt_1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/txt_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nivedita Parmar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="home"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView21"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView21"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_height"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_height"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="home"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/txt_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it works fine,but i had to add number of things under the same view and they get attached to that view.please see if you could add number of image view and text view under that divider.

Comment: sure, but you have to provide me design otherwise I attached with multiple views as per my assumption.

Comment: you can add four text views one under other and image view infront of them. all this under the view and above view it could be one text view and image view

Comment: i had added the image u can see it

Comment: I edit my answer but not as per your image but this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline). I've found it to be useful when working with Constraint Views.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```